# How can I make wordpress stop permalinking non wp directories?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How can I make my WordPress install stop taking over directories that it has nothing to do with?

I have a directory thats password protected via `.htaccess` and when it wasn't protected, I could access it, but now that it is, it throws a WordPress 404 page.

this is the existing WordPress `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The directory I'm trying to protect is

```
/software/development/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress should only kick in when the requested directory or file doesn't exist, so I'm assuming that you were relying on FancyIndexing to get a directory listing of `/software/development`?  If so, then you should be able to stick a `.htaccess` file in that directory to turn off request rewriting:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```