# Wordpress Intalled on a separate directory and .htaccess redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've installed my wordpress site on a separate directory and followed all the steps [described here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and now I can access my site from my main domain.  So, my Wordpress site is installed under: www.mysite.com/wp-site/ and now I can access my site under www.mysite.com, so all is great, exactly what I wanted.  Wordpress is making this happen through an .htaccess file it creates that has the necessary code to make the redirection happen (SEE CODE BELOW).

**My problem is that I have other directories on my site, such as www.mysite.com/another-directory-unrelated-to-wordpress/ that I cannot access anymore because I believe wordpress and the .htaccess file it created is redirecting everything to the root.**

How can I avoid Wordpress from redirecting all my other subfolders and files? Thanks a ton for any ideas or help.

Here is the htaccess file code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the WordPress .htaccess file works is if an existing file or directory is requested, it does *not* send the request through WordPress...that's what the `!-f` and `!-d` `RewriteCond` statements do.

So, there is something else going on with your site. Have you used Firebug or any other debugging tool to see what is happening with the request/response?

You could always enable mod_rewrite logging to see if that gives you a clue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteLog "rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

A `RewriteLogLevel` of 5 would give you the most information. Make sure to comment out or remove the RewriteLog* lines when you have figured out the issue.

**UPDATE:** Check [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232935/how-can-i-make-wordpress-stop-permalinking-non-wp-directories/1233100#1233100) to see if it resolves your issue